# S3 ,verify a signed URL in PHP, Deconstruct signed URL

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, signature

I am using s3 direct uploads along with a database to store the URLS of the files (along with other data like who uploaded etc). 
To allow direct upload to s3, I'm creating a presigned URL like :

```
$s3 = App::make('aws')->createClient('s3', [
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA',
                'secret' => 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY',
            ]

        ]);


 $command = $s3->getCommand('PutObject', [

            '@use_accelerate_endpoint'=>true,
            'Bucket' => 'remdev-experimental',
            'Key' => "newest newest.txt",
            'Metadata' => array(
                'foo' => "test",
            )
        ]);



        return response()->json(((string)$s3->createPresignedRequest($command, '+1 minutes')->getUri()));
```

Now, after the file from the client has finished uploading , I want my server to know about it. So I will require the client to send me a request , notifying about the fact that he has finished uploading. For this, I think the simplest(and also secure) way is to just allow the client to send back the signed URL that he just sent back.

Is there a way to parse the URL ? 
I am interested in getting the object key , and more importantly , I want to verify that the URL has not been tampered with (meaning, the signature in the URL should match the rest of the contents). How can I do this in php sdk ?

Comment: NEVER SHARE YOUR AWS CREDENTIALS!!!!. You should immediately change your IAM access keys so these don't work. When posting, you should "mask" your credentials by just posting 'key' => 'AXXXXXXXXX', 'secret' => 'YYYYYYY', or something similar.

Comment: I had taken care to change the key. It was some random stuff that I came up with

Comment: They worked for me to do a ListObject request

Comment: damn, i thought that would prevent anybody from bothering. lol 
i have deactivated the keys now. Thanks for bringing it to my notice. I completely forgot that I had added the lines

Answer (score 1):

The signed URL is the file's URL with the signature information in the query data. So a signed request for bucket: `remdev-experimental` file: `abc.txt` looks like `https://s3.amazonaws.com/remdev-experimental/abc.txt?X-Amz-Date=date&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Signature=signature&X-Amz-Credential=SOMEID/20160703/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=Host&x-amz-security-token=some-long-token` so all you need to do is get the URL's Path (`/remdev-experimental/abc.txt` and take everything after the 2nd slash.

Also you should be aware that you can have S3 redirect the browser to a URL using `success_action_redirect` in an [HTTP post policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html)

Lastly you can have S3 trigger a notification to your server (via SQS, SNS, or Lambda) whenever a file is uploaded.

Comment: I don't understand. my question is ,say a hacker gets my signed URL , and changes abc.txt to something else (which he didnt have a signed url of), and he sends this to my server (I will now instead do this redirect step automatically , as you suggested). In my EC2 server, how do I verify The Url against the signature ? Which I am assuming is the Signature key in the query parameter. if I understood whatever you said , I should take everything after ABC.txt and BEFORE Signature=signature , and sign using sha256 ?

Comment: I don't think there's a way for you to verify that the URL matches the signature. You can just query s3 to see if the file exists

Comment: its possible that the file exists , which was uploaded by somebody else, but this hacker has changed the name. 
basically I want a fool proof way of telling my ec2 server that A signed url file upload has been uploaded (without using lambda)